# Is tkinter PhotoImage always being redefined?

Tags: python, tkinter, while-loop, tkinter-canvas

I have already asked a similar question on the subject, in which I asked why only the last picture from the list (with 3 pictures) is only displayed for a list index out of range error. I have solved this problem, the last picture from the list is now displayed when I set "bildertimer" to 3. Still, only the last picture is shown to me. Is the photo image variable always redefined? And how I can change it? Here is the code:

```
        pics = glob.glob('/path/to/folder/*.png')
        pics = (sorted(pics, key=os.path.getmtime))
        pics = pics[::-1]
        bildertimer = 3
        bild = 0
        x_koo = 0
        y_koo = 0
        bilderraum = Canvas(width=1750, height=930)
        bilderraum.place(x=130, y=20)
        while bildertimer > 0:
            if x_koo > 1430:
                x_koo = 0
                y_koo = y_koo + 200
            img = PhotoImage(file=pics[bild])
            img.image = pics[bild]
            img_small = img.subsample(8)
            bilderraum.create_image(x_koo, y_koo, anchor='nw', image=img_small)
            bilderraum.image = img_small
            bildertimer = bildertimer - 1
            bild = bild + 1
            x_koo = x_koo + 340
```

Comment: The previous images are being garbage-collected, because you no longer have a reference to them.  Append them all to a list, perhaps.

Comment: They are appended to the pics-list, or not? Can you post an example?

Comment: You have a list of filenames - that doesn't do you any good, as nothing needs the filenames afterwards.  You need a list of all the values assigned to `img_small`.

Comment: Thanks! it works! That was easier, than I thought!